# How do I wire a a new light switch to old wiring?

Tags: multiway-switch, uk

The far right (looking from the back) is one way and the left is two way. How would I wire this into a new socket? I presume it’s still the two red live into the 2 way, etc.

The new device:

[image: new switch]

The existing wiring:

[image: old wired]

Comment: I'm an American, so this is probably a "2 people separated by a common language" issue - When you say "new socket" are you replacing a switch with a switch, or a switch with a receptacle (that a cord would plug into)?

Comment: Also, it's hard to tell from the wired one, are the labels for the holes the same on the 2 devices? If so, it would make sense to simply transfer like-to-like...

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting but Bart Van (in the replies) gave the perfect answer which worked

Comment: Well, he answered an hour after my comment, and there's at least 1 other person who agreed with me (up vote on the comment). In the future, the more detail you can provide, the easier it is for others to answer.

Comment: All good, No worries man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look carefully at the picture of your old switch, you can see the word "common" near where the two reds are connected. This corresponds to the "COM" marking on the new switch.

What this tells you is that between the old and the new switch, the top and bottom sides are swapped. To connect the new switch:

- Connect the black, red, white and blue wires in that order to the connections labeled 1(way), 2, 1(way) and 2.
- Connect the two reds and the other end of the short red wire to the connections labeled COM.

If you have trouble connecting the double red without bare wire showing, then the connector is too small to hold two wires and you need to make a small adjustment to the wiring.

- Cut another short piece of wire and strip the ends bare.
- Connect the (permanent) live red and the two short wires together with a wire-nut or connector block.
- Connect each of the short wires to one of the COM connections of the switch.

Comment: Thank you very much it’s working , do you have a PayPal I can send to but you a drink please ?

Comment: I am happy my answer was useful. I appreciate the offer for drinks, but I will have to decline. You can, however, upvote the answer and/or click the check-mark. Those are the customary ways of showing that an answer was helpful.

Comment: Thanks again Bart, I’ve cast a vote (says I need 15 feedback, but it’s been recorded ) and have clicked the tick.